# TimerControl "keeps" the focus while refreshing

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-controls

I've created a UserControl with a standard windows form timer and a label. The label would be refreshed by the timer every second in the format hh:mm:ss using backgroundworker. The label wouldn't update because only the UI thread can do this. So I've put this code to make it work:

```
    delegate void RefreshTimerCallback(string text);
    private void RefreshTimer(string text)
    {
            if (lblTiming.InvokeRequired)
            {
                RefreshTimerCallback d = RefreshTimer;
                Invoke(d, text);
            }
            else
            {
                lblTiming.Text = text;
            }
    }
```

Everything is working fine now except one thing. It seems the UserControl always 'take over' the focus. What I mean is, when I put the UserControl on a panel with scrollbars, it always scrolls back up to the UserControl when I scroll down.

The question is, is there a better way to update the label within the UserControl? Or maybe better, can I tell the UserControl to not take over the focus?

Comment: Off-topic, but you might want to consider using `BeginInvoke` rather than `Invoke` as the latter can lead to thread deadlock

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I've already try this: 
lblTiming.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lblTiming.Text = Time.ToString(); }); 
But it doesn't seem to have solved my problem, so I try the code in my first post.

Comment: Set the label's AutoSize property to False to fix your problem.  You don't need it, displayed time is always about the same size. Right now you don't like the layout recalculation that occurs when you assign the Text property, the *possibly* different layout triggers the ScrollableControl.ScrollControlIntoView() method.  Which is what you are complaining about.

Comment: I've done exactly what Hans has told me and problem is solved. Thank you Hans! You've saved my butt and big time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have disabled the AutoSize property of the lable to False and the problem is solved. Thanks for the tip Hans!